# Axios data as undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to send a post request through axios, and I get an error saying that params I passed are undefined. I have verified through debugging that the data I pass to the post function is not undefined and is correct as should be, so I don't understand why I get the undefined error.

Here is my work so far;

**POST Function**

```
export function userSignupPostRequest(userData){
    return dispatch => {

        return axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: BASE_URL + '/api/user/',
            data: {
                name: userData.username,
                passwordDigest: userData.passwordDigest,
                email: userData.email
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Event for calling POST function**

```
import User from "../../pojo/user";

.....

onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(this.isValid()){
        this.setState({ errors: {}, isLoading: true });
        var newUser = User(this.state.username, this.state.password, this.state.email);
        this.props.userSignupPostRequest(newUser)
            .then(
                () => {
                    this.props.addFlashMessage({
                        type: "success",
                        text: "You signed up successfully. Welcome!"
                    })
                    this.context.router.push("/");
                },
                ({ data }) => this.setState({ errors: data, isLoading: false })
            )
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    }
}
```

**User Class**

```
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const SALT_SIZE = 10;

export function encryptPassword(password){
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, SALT_SIZE);
}

export default function User(username, password, email){
    var passwordDigest = encryptPassword(password);

    return {
        username: username,
        passwordDigest: passwordDigest,
        email: email
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
at SignupForm.render (SignupForm.js?2314:73)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (ReactCompositeComponent.js?195a:815)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?195a:841)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?195a:773)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (ReactCompositeComponent.js?195a:753)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?195a:672)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performUpdateIfNecessary (ReactCompositeComponent.js?195a:585)
at Object.performUpdateIfNecessary (ReactReconciler.js?3d8b:160)
at runBatchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js?371c:151)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (Transaction.js?fbf2:136)
```

As I said I don't understand why I get this error as I can verify that `userData` of `userSignupPostRequest` is not undefined. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There seem to be some problems with your code. First of all, I guess it should be `var newUser = new User(this.state.u....` instead of `var newUser = User(this.state.u....`.

Comment: You need to bind `onSubmit` or use an arrow function. Your function is not able to read `this.state`.

Comment: So I have included the User class and the import statement on the calling class. Now I am new to js, so excuse if its not the best written code

Comment: According to the error message, the error is in the `render()` method of your `SignupForm` class. Did you check that? Are you maybe trying to access `this.state.user.username` with `this.state.user` being blank?

Comment: But I have debugged that when I click the onSubmit button and enter the `userSignupPostRequest` function, the param `userData` has all the required information

Comment: Ok, but what is line 73 in SignupForm.js?

Comment: Hmmm that is a param passed to another react component - `error={errors.username}`. I'll try a test and see if its that `username` value that is throwing the issue. Thanks, I didn't realise the 73 was the line number